# Docker pull giving connection reset by peer error

Tags: docker, pull, docker-image

I have installed `Docker` on `Ubuntu` machine. I have problem with `docker pull` command, I am getting `connection reset by peer` error.

```
root@machine1:~# docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: read tcp 10.80.64.126:51404->54.152.209.167:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

command : `docker images` worked and gave empty result as no image is downloaded on docker host. But as this command is working, shows docker installed successfully.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED        SIZE
```

My docker version is `1.13.1`.
How can I solve this problem?